# Print a text and set it to a variable BATCH

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm making a program that allows you to register from the software. I have tryied a lot of commands but no one does what I want. In the example below I'm only making the USER EXAMPLE:

```
:REGISTER    
set/p USR=Set your new user:    
echo.>"USER.txt"    
break>"USER.txt"    
@echo %USR% > USER.txt    
:LOGIN
set/p LOGUSER=Enter your user:
```

[I want to compare %LOGUSER% with the text in USER.txt] --> then goto OK.

Thank you!!

PS: Excuse me about my spelling mistakes!

Comment: why do you echoing blank to user.txt and then delete all its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `user.txt` contains only one line (your code overwrites it three times), it's quite simple:

```
set /p textuser=<USER.txt
if /i "%loguser%"=="%textuser%" goto ok
```

PS:

```
@echo %USR% > USER.txt
```

writes an unintended space to the output, which makes comparing difficult. Better write:

```
@echo %USR%>USER.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:REGISTER
@echo off
set/p USR=Set your new user:

echo.>"USER.txt"

break>"USER.txt"

@echo %USR%>USER.txt

:LOGIN

set/p LOGUSER=Enter your user:

::::  -- HERE'S THE MAIN THING --   ::::
<"USER.txt" set /p line=
if "%line%" EQU "%LOGUSER%" goto :OK
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

echo not ok
exit /b 1
:ok
echo ok
```